# Keras model.load_weights() error: ValueError: Invalid high library version bound (invalid high library version bound)

Tags: python, docker, keras, theano, h5py

I use [Docker from Gadgetron](https://hub.docker.com/r/gadgetron/ubuntu_1804_no_cuda) to realize a Gadget with Keras. Theano as backend. Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/thomaskuestner/CNNArt/blob/yang_liu/Gadgetron/Dockerfile) and the result of `pip list` is

```
Package              Version    
-------------------- -----------
absl-py              0.7.1      
astor                0.8.0      
certifi              2019.6.16  
chardet              3.0.4      
cycler               0.10.0     
Cython               0.26.1     
decorator            4.4.0      
dicom                0.9.9.post1
dicom-numpy          0.1.6      
engineering-notation 0.6.0      
gast                 0.2.2      
google-pasta         0.1.7      
grpcio               1.21.1     
h5py                 2.9.0      
idna                 2.8        
imageio              2.5.0      
ismrmrd              1.6.1      
ismrmrd-python-tools 0.3        
joblib               0.13.2     
Keras                2.2.4      
Keras-Applications   1.0.8      
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0      
kiwisolver           1.1.0      
lxml                 4.2.1      
Markdown             3.1.1      
matplotlib           3.1.0      
networkx             2.3        
numpy                1.16.4     
opencv-python        4.1.0.25   
Pillow               6.0.0      
pip                  19.2.3     
protobuf             3.8.0      
psutil               5.4.2      
pydicom              1.2.2      
pygobject            3.26.1     
pynrrd               0.4.0      
pyparsing            2.4.0      
PyQt5                5.12.2     
PyQt5-sip            4.19.17    
python-apt           1.6.4      
python-dateutil      2.8.0      
pytz                 2019.2     
PyWavelets           1.0.3      
PyXB                 1.2.6      
PyYAML               5.1.1      
pyzmq                18.0.2     
requests             2.22.0     
scikit-image         0.15.0     
scikit-learn         0.21.2     
scipy                1.3.0      
setuptools           41.0.1     
six                  1.12.0     
sklearn              0.0        
tensorboard          1.14.0     
tensorboardX         1.8        
tensorflow           1.14.0     
tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0     
tensorflow-gpu       1.14.0     
termcolor            1.1.0      
Theano               1.0.4      
tk-tools             0.11.0     
torch                1.1.0      
torchfile            0.1.0      
torchvision          0.3.0      
tornado              6.0.3      
urllib3              1.25.3     
visdom               0.1.8.8    
websocket-client     0.56.0     
Werkzeug             0.15.4     
wheel                0.33.4     
wrapt                1.11.2
```

Mycode is like this:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

with open('/opt/data/model.json', 'r') as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read())
model.load_weights('/opt/data/weight.h5')
```

When loading the weights, an error appeared:

```
File "/opt/data/CNNArt/Gadgetron/gadget_cnnart.py", line 29, in process
    model.load_weights('/opt/data/weight.h5')

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1157, in load_weights
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 391, in __init__
    fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, **kwds)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 108, in make_fapl
    plist.set_libver_bounds(low, high)

  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py/h5p.pyx", line 1140, in h5py.h5p.PropFAID.set_libver_bounds

ValueError: Invalid high library version bound (invalid high library version bound)
```

However, in Docker, when I opened python **in the terminal**, I can load the model and its parameters.

```
>>> from keras.models import model_from_json
>>> with open('/opt/data/model.json', 'r') as f:
...     model = model_from_json(f.read())
...
>>> model.load_weights('/opt/data/weight.h5')
>>>
```

I have tried to reinstall `h5py` with `pip`, but it doesn't work.

The problem is it works directly in python interaction terminal but doesn't work in Gadget script.

Comment: you need to show your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall h5py and reinstall with this command:

```
pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
```

[Source](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/gmsh-4-4-1-in-fenics-meshio/1415)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and I solve it with installing

```
sudo apt-get install python3-h5py
```

and make sure that numpy version is compatible with h5py

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when using tensorflow.

as mentioned by @so2liu, Please try:

```
pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
```

however, Make sure you choose a version compatible with tensorflow or some other lib, for example:

```
pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py==2.10.0
```

At last, remeber checke your env, as you might runing your code in venv / conda / docker but you installed h5py in the wrong env

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I have tried various methods for reinstalling/upgrading packages, but in the end, I changed the model's save method : save_model ("model name") instead of simply saving the model as an H5 file. Finally, I loaded the model ：tf.keras.load_model ("model name"),it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).